# Normalizr - where would I modify an entity?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, normalizr

So I ran ahead and normalized all the entities in my reducers, which means each reducer has a separate `entities` object. I now realise it makes more sense for *one* reducer to have *all* entities in it, then just store IDs (such as currentUser or something) in separate reducers.

This approach makes complete sense for merging in entities from an API response, but I can't work out how I'd *change* any entity.

For example, where would I do an operation like this?

```
    case SUBSCRIBER_TOGGLED: {
        let projectSubscriberIDs = cloneDeep(action.payload.project.subscriberIDs);

        let indexIfExists = projectSubscriberIDs.indexOf(action.payload.user.id);

        if(indexIfExists != -1){
            projectSubscriberIDs.splice(indexIfExists, 1);
        }else{
            projectSubscriberIDs.push(action.payload.user.id);
        }

        return {
            ...state,
            entities: {
                ...state.entities,
                projects: {
                    ...state.entities.projects,
                    [action.payload.project.id]: {
                        ...action.payload.project,
                        subscriberIDs: projectSubscriberIDs
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

- we can't work this out earlier in an action, as actions can't know what's in state
- we can't do this in a reducer that doesn't contain the relevant entities, as reducers can't/shouldn't access other reducers
- it feels wrong to do all of these in the `entities` reducer, as it'll become an enormous mess

Anyone have any insights here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few thoughts:

- An action creator *can* know what's in state, as `redux-thunk` lets you write functions that have access to `getState()`.
- Slice reducers *can* have access to data that's in other state slices, per [the Redux FAQ entry on sharing state between slice reducers](https://redux.js.org/faq/reducers#how-do-i-share-state-between-two-reducers-do-i-have-to-use-combinereducers).
- There's a lot of other options out there for managing normalized state in Redux besides Normalizr.  I personally am a fan of the [Redux-ORM library](https://github.com/tommikaikkonen/redux-orm), and have written about it extensively in my ["Practical Redux" tutorial series](http://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/series/practical-redux).
- In that series, I've specifically shown an approach for [writing "feature reducers" that have access to the entire root state tree](http://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2017/01/practical-redux-part-7-forms-editing-reducers/), as well as [generic logic for updating any entity based on its type and ID](http://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2017/01/practical-redux-part-8-form-draft-data-management/).
- Finally, you might also want to look into the [`immer` immutable update library](https://github.com/mweststrate/immer/) to simplify updating that nested state.

Comment: Spectacular answer markerikson - 'immer' sounds amazing and I'm gonna go read all your posts now. Perhaps I'm thinking through this the wrong way. Cheers!